# I am trying to implement an Ajax webform with multiple outputs, but it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a problem. I am trying to develop exercises, where after answering them, you can know if each answer is right or wrong, and I am using json to retrieve the responses as I could read in this forum. The problem is that the AJAX code is not working, it is not showing anything. I don't know where my mistake is.

This is the Ajax (jQuery is installed properly). By the way, the console also throw me this error: "Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0" within console.fail function(), although if I delete that piece of code, anyway the AJAX form doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var request;

  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  if (request) {
        request.abort();
  }

  var $form = $(this);

  var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

  var serializedData = $form.serialize();

  // $inputs.prop("disabled", true);

  request = $.ajax({
          data:  serializedData,
          url:   'exercise_matching_code.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type:  'post',
          success:  function (data) {
            $(".message1").html(data.message1);
            $(".message2").html(data.message2);
            $(".message3").html(data.message3);
            $(".message4").html(data.message4);
            $(".message5").html(data.message5);
          }
    });
   // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });
    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
  });
});
```

This is the PHP File

```
<?php
$a = $_POST["a"];
$b = $_POST["b"];
$c = $_POST["c"];
$d = $_POST["d"];
$e = $_POST["e"];
if ($a == '2') {
    $answer1 = "correct answer";
    echo $answer1;
} else {
    $answer1 = "wrong answer";
    echo $answer1;
}
if ($b == '4') {
    $answer2 = "correct answer";
} else {
    $answer2 = "wrong answer";
}
if ($c == '1') {
    $answer3 = "correct answer";
} else {
    $answer3 = "wrong answer";
}
if ($b == '5') {
    $answer4 = "correct answer";
} else {
    $answer4 = "wrong answer";
}
if ($b == '3') {
    $answer5 = "correct answer";
} else {
    $answer5 = "wrong answer";
}
echo json_encode(
  array(
    "message1" => "$answer1", 
    "message2" => "$answer2",
    "message3" => "$answer3",
    "message4" => "$answer4",
    "message5" => "$answer5",
  )
) 
?>
```

And finally, this is the HTML form:

```
</script>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="large-12 columns">
     <p>Übung: Finde das Gegenteil:</p>
     <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>a) schön</td>
        <td>1 alt</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b) groß</td>
        <td>2 klein</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c) neu</td>
        <td>3 langweilig</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>d) laut</td>
        <td>4 leise</td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>e) interessant</td>
        <td>5 hässlich</td> 
      </tr>
     </table>
     </div>
  </div>
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="large-12 columns">
       <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <td>a)</td>
        <td>
          <select name="a">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="message1"></div>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b)</td>
        <td>
          <select name="b">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="message2"></div>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c)</td>
        <td>
          <select name="c">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="message3"></div>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>d)</td>
        <td>
          <select name="d">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="message4"></div>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>e)</td>
        <td>
          <select name="e">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
          </select>
          <div class="message5"></div>
        </td> 
      </tr>
      <tr>
     </table>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns submitting">
        <input type="submit" value="Go" class="submit">
        </div>
       </div>
  </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: didn't you post this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/42794716/1415724 and got an answer that you accepted? or is this a totally different issue?

Comment: Consider using a loop instead of a separate conditional expression for every variable.

Comment: That was a different issue Fred. In that case I solved the problem (the webpage was refreshing when I clicked the submit button. This is another different. Thanks.

Comment: no problemo @AlvaroLópezSánchez

Answer (score 2):

I think that your problem lies here:

```
if ($a == '2') {
    $answer1 = "correct answer";
    echo $answer1;
} else {
    $answer1 = "wrong answer";
    echo $answer1;
}
```

You print out something before outputting a JSON-encoded array, so when you fetch that page with AJAX and set the data-type to `JSON`, it expects valid JSON and nothing else.

> Unexpected token w in JSON at position 0

This error confirms it, more or less. Your script outputs "**w**rong answer" in the beginning, so JSON parsing stops at the very first character.

**EDIT:** Also, after the conditional for `c`, you forgot to change the variables from `b` to `d` and `e`. To prevent such mistakes you need to refactor your code. There's no need for multiple conditionals in this case, you should use loops. Consider this script:

```
<?php
$correctAnswers = Array(
    "a" => 2,
    "b" => 4,
    "c" => 1,
    "d" => 5,
    "e" => 3
);

$messages = Array();
$messageNumber = 1;

foreach($correctAnswers as $question => $correctAnswer) {
    if($_POST[$question] == $correctAnswer) {
        $messages["message".$messageNumber] = "correct answer";
    } else {
        $messages["message".$messageNumber] = "wrong answer";
    }
    $messageNumber++;
}

print(json_encode($messages));
?>
```

This should be 100% compatible with your JS and HTML form, so you can try it out right away. It's much cleaner and isn't as error-prone.

Comment: Thanks, this is correct. I solved this and it works!

Comment: There are more mistakes in your code, check the edit to my answer.